# Get empty when deleting AliCloud tableStore's data

Tags: python

When I use python SDK to delete TableStore's data, the method get_range() always returns empty array and cannot continue to use BatchWriteRowRequest to delete data. And I have tried Java SDK too, it also does not work.

Thanks in advance.

```
consumed, next_start_primary_key, row_list, next_token = client.get_range(
    table_name, Direction.BACKWARD,
    exclusive_end_primary_key,
    inclusive_start_primary_key,
    columns_to_get=[] //all columns
)
```

row_list is always empty like [].

Comment: Please ensure to provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.